How to draw curve arrows among under/over braces
I have the following code
            \begin{center}
    $\underbrace{\text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}}\,}$
    $\underbrace{\text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}}\,}$
    {\text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}}\,}

    *snip*

    \scalebox{1.75}{$\text{\textbf{:}}$} \\ \smallskip
    $\overbrace{\,\text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}\,} \text{\scalebox{1.75}{$\bullet$}}\,}$
\end{center}

I would like to draw curve arrows from the lower brace to the upper ones:

Is there a easy way (say, without tizk)?

There is not "easy way", try by use of tikzmark library of tikz package.

@Zarko, I see, thanks. I am looking at here. Is there a way to name the cusp of a brace? (I am on vacation, I'll be back in a fortnight)
